# execute bat throw php script deployed on iis server

Tags: php, android, iis, wamp

I want to execute this file.bat from php script  deployed in  IIS server :

```
android 1>> log.log 2>> erreur.log
```

the problem is that when I double click over the file it works but when I try it from web  using this simple code it doesn't

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p>Hello word !!!!!!!</p>
<a href="<?php exec('file.bat');?>"> click me</a>
</body>
</html>
```

and I get this error in the log file.

```
'android.exe' n'est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
ou externe, un programme ex‚cutable ou un fichier de commandes.
```

is that rely to role and permission?? because I get this log file on WAMP

```
[8444:7948:0701/101205:ERROR:policy_loader_win.cc(531)] GetAppliedGPOList scope 1: L’opération a réussi.
[8444:7948:0701/101205:ERROR:policy_loader_win.cc(531)] GetAppliedGPOList scope 0: L’opération a réussi.
[8444:7948:0701/102705:ERROR:policy_loader_win.cc(531)] GetAppliedGPOList scope 1: L’opération a réussi.
[8444:7948:0701/102705:ERROR:policy_loader_win.cc(531)] GetAppliedGPOList scope 0: L’opération a réussi.
```

any would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem 1: wrong use of `href`**

If you wish to execute a php script `scrip.php` by clicking a `HTML` link, then write this anchor tag:

```
<a href="/path/to/my/script.php">Doit</a>
```

And in `script.php`, you write your `exec('file.bat');` statement.

Like you have written your code, PHP will first execute your script, get the result from the script back (which is empty as every output is forwarded to files) and fills the empty result in the `href` attribute. So, try to understand more precise, what in PHP is interpreted, what is executed and what is delivered to the web browser.

**Problem 2: several PHP configurations**

If you double click your `file.bat`-file, PHP is basically started from CLI (command line interface). If you start it by your web browser by clicking the link, then PHP is started probably as an Apache module.

In both situations PHP may have a complete different configuration.

In order to find out what configuration is in action, create a script containing only

```
<?php 
   phpinfo();
?>
```

and start this script once from CLI (i.d. Windows command shell) and once in a web browser and compare the results. You'll find much details about modules loaded, variables set and the configuration used. It will tell you something like this:

```
...
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc
...
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /Library/Server/Web/Config/php
...
```

This will explain the differences between start by double click and start by browser tag.

Try to find out more about the `php.ini` e.g. here: http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php

Having different configurations at the begin maybe difficult to handle, but it makes sense.

Good luck :-)

Comment: you say that 
"If you double click your file.bat-file, PHP is basically started from CLI (command line interface). If you start it by your web browser by clicking the link, then PHP is started probably as an Apache module."
but double click my file.bat-file does'nt mean that PHP is started from CLI. I just say that because I think that the problem comes from user permession to excute android

Comment: Just make sure that there are not several `php.ini` files, or if there are, check specifically what the ini file for http allows. But first, try writing a real link into the `href` attribute :-)

Comment: I think the problem come from that iis can read the Path variable.
and all are ok if I put the absolute path.
so how can I let IIS read path variables ???